# How can I provide multiple source inputs for a build config in Openshift

Tags: openshift, buildconfig

I want to create a builder image `app_name:latest` which would take multiple source inputs, e.g, another image and a binary source, then create output into `app_name:latest`.

**Example -**

```
{
    "kind": "BuildConfig",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "app_name",
        "labels": {
            "application": "app_name"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "source": {
            "type": "Git",
            "git": {
                "uri": "https://github.com/xyz/app_name.git",
                "ref": "master"
            },
            "contextDir": ""
        },
        "strategy": {
            "type": "Source",
            "sourceStrategy": {
                "from": {
                    "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                    "namespace": "openshift",
                    "name": "java-s2i:latest"
                }
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "to": {
                "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                "name": "app_name:latest"
            }
        },
        "triggers": [{
                "type": "GitHub",
                "generic": {
                    "secret": "secret"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Generic",
                "github": {
                    "secret": "secret"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "ImageChange",
                "imageChange": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use what is called a chained build.

When using `oc new-build` to create the image, use the following options:

```
--source-image='': Specify an image to use as source for the build. You must also specify --source-image-path.
--source-image-path='': Specify the file or directory to copy from the source image and its destination in the build directory. Format:
```

The argument to `--source-image` is the name of an existing image stream created from a separate build. This could contain other pre-compiled artifacts or data files.

The argument to `--source-image-path` is an absolute in the image where files are copied from, and a relative pathname within the directory of uploaded files injected by the source build, where the files from the separate image should be placed. The latter cannot be an absolute path, so you would have to possibly override the `assemble` script to move it into the correct location.

As far as what this looks like in raw build configuration, it is:

```
    "source": {
        "git": {
            "ref": "master",
            "uri": "https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook"
        },
        "images": [
            {
                "from": {
                    "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                    "name": "packages-python-27:latest"
                },
                "paths": [
                    {
                        "destinationDir": ".s2i",
                        "sourcePath": "/opt/app-root/packages"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "from": {
                    "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                    "name": "packages-python-35-wheelhouse:latest"
                },
                "paths": [
                    {
                        "destinationDir": ".s2i",
                        "sourcePath": "/opt/app-root/packages"
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
    },
},
```

When adding to the raw build configuration directly, you can have more than one image source. The command line only allows one to be set up.